# Titanium Appcelerator - After enabling cloud services I get UnicodeDecodeError when compiling for Android

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I've got an app that has a UTF8 name (hebrew). I use the platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml file for this.
I've managed to narrow it down to the Ti.cloudpush module.
only when I enable this module I get the error.

I used to be able to compile it to android without any issues but as soon as I enable cloud services I get this error -

```
[ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]   File "/Users/Shahar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.0.GA/android/builder.py", line 2218, in <module>
[ERROR]     s.build_and_run(True, None, key, password, alias, output_dir)
[ERROR]   File "/Users/Shahar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.0.GA/android/builder.py", line 1970, in build_and_run
[ERROR]     self.manifest_changed = self.generate_android_manifest(compiler)
[ERROR]   File "/Users/Shahar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.0.GA/android/builder.py", line 1195, in generate_android_manifest
[ERROR]     custom_manifest_contents = fill_manifest(custom_manifest_contents)
[ERROR]   File "/Users/Shahar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.0.GA/android/builder.py", line 1122, in fill_manifest
[ERROR]     manifest_source = manifest_source.replace(ti_permissions,permissions_required_xml)
[ERROR] UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 501: ordinal not in range(128)
```

and this is my manifest file with the part that causes the issues.
If I remove the hebrew name, it compiles without any issues

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
    android:label="??????"
    android:name="QuestionnaireApplication"
    android:debuggable="false"
>
    <activity
        android:name=".QuestionnaireActivity"
        android:label="??????"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
    >
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In Titanium Studio, on the toolbar, click on Project -> Clean. Rebuild.